# Plot line chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot the probability of any 'shotType' being a goal as 'shotDistance' increases. Plotting probability of a shot being a goal based on 'shotType' as 'shotDistance' increases. I want the y-axis to be a percent of 0 to 1 based on value of '%total' and the x-axis to be 'shotDistance' min to 'shotDistance' max - roughly 0 to 100. My I don't have really any experience with matplotlib besides plotting lines and histograms with simple datasets. Not sure where to start.

My code:

```
allPlayerShotStats =shots.groupby(['shotType','shotDistance','event'])['event'].agg(['count'])
allPlayerShotStats['%total'] =allPlayerShotStats.groupby(['shotDistance','event'])['count'].apply(lambda x: x / sum(x))

allPlayerShotStats
```

Returns:

```
    shotType    shotDistance    event   count   %total
0   BACK    1.000000        GOAL    3       0.214286
1   BACK    1.000000        SHOT    1       0.142857
2   BACK    1.414214        GOAL    6       0.206897
3   BACK    1.414214        MISS    1       0.166667
4   BACK    1.414214        SHOT    4       0.137931
... ... ... ... ... ...
25240   WRIST   97.169954   SHOT    4       0.444444
25241   WRIST   97.508974   SHOT    1       1.000000
25242   WRIST   97.575612   SHOT    8       0.571429
25243   WRIST   97.989795   GOAL    1       1.000000
25244   WRIST   97.989795   SHOT    4       0.800000
```

I've been playing around with various techniques but I'm not knowledgeable enough to really know what I'm doing with matplotlib.

In

```
plt.plot(allPlayerShotStats["shotDistance"].values, allPlayerShotStats["%total"].values)
```

Out

[image]

Comment: Try something like this `plt.plot(allPlayerShotStats["shotDistance"].values, allPlayerShotStats["%total"].values)`

Comment: I edited what it returned. On the right track but the plot line isn't looking too good. Thinking I need to restructure the input but not sure where to start

Comment: How about a scatter plot? `plt.scatter(allPlayerShotStats["shotDistance"].values, allPlayerShotStats["%total"].values`

Comment: I would recommend reading through some of their examples here --> https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

Comment: It is too regular because of the sample data, but if you replace it with your data, you will get the intended graph. I think a scatter plot would be best, as mentioned in the comments; I've changed from `count()` to `size()`, but it's equivalent. I've expanded it into a [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ap7LSoda6IZeAJfee02laiPcjRg2jgWG?usp=sharing), please refer to it.

Comment: If you check Colab, it will disable the link. I will respond to this code again if needed.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you did. I appreciate your thoroughness. I added a photo to the collab to show what I'm intending to recreate.

Comment: I couldn't check the images, but I'm glad you found it useful. The Colab link will be disabled. I don't need any more answers.